# mysql php result using zipcode and restaurant status

Tags: mysql

I've restaurant table with zipcode. I've searched with zipcode '2600'. so I need to display the result based on searched zipcode and then list other zipcode.
First, display zipcode 2600 with open status.
Second, display other zipcode with open status.
third, display zipcode 2600 with closed status.
Fourth, diplay other zipcode with closed status.

```
resid   resname zipcode resstatus
1   Res1    2500    Open
2   Res2    2505    Closed
3   Res3    2600    Open
4   Res4    2510    Closed
5   Res5    2600    Closed
6   Res6    2610    Open
7   Res7    2700    Open
```

I need to display the output like below.....

```
resid   resname zipcode 
3   Res3    2600    Open
5   Res1    2500    Open
1   Res6    2610    Open
2   Res7    2700    Open
4   Res5    2600    Closed
6   Res2    2505    Closed
7   Res4    2510    Closed
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY FIELD(resstatus, 'Open') DESC,FIELD(zipcode, 2600) DESC;
```

**[SQL Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/478394/2)**

**Output**

```
resid  resname  zipcode resstatus
1   Res1    2600    Open
3   Res3    2500    Open
5   Res5    2300    Open
4   Res4    2600    Closed
2   Res2    2700    Closed
```

Comment: Please add a record 6 Res6 2600 Closed.
Its not working as per my requirements